# Crashwrangler or !exploitable equivalent for Android

Tags: android, security

Is there an equivalent of !exploitable for Android? [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com) and [ACRA](http://acra.ch) does not seem to have exploitability analysis for crashes for Android. Does anyone know of any tool in Android that does it? Please advise thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer is a bit late, but I hope it can help someone in the future.

There is the [exploitable](https://github.com/jfoote/exploitable) extension for GDB that may be what you are looking for.  You can set up GDB in [remote debugging mode](https://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/how-cc-debugging-works-on-android/) and connect it to your android application.

Comment: No, it isn't late. Thanks!